# Error with Snowflake .NET Driver for Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have implemented the solution described here for connecting ADF to Snowflake: https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-connector-for-azure-data-factory-adf/

This solution uses Azure Function and the Snowflake .Net Driver (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dotnet-driver.html)

I have been successful until now by connecting to Snowflake by user and password. For example: `account=testaccount;user=testuser;password=XXXXX;db=testdb;schema=testschema`

However due to security concerns I need to change this connection type to Key-Value pair:

```
account=testaccount;authenticator=snowflake_jwt;user=testuser;private_key_file={pathToThePrivateKeyFile};private_key_pwd={passwordForDecryptingThePrivateKey};db=testdb;schema=testschema
```

However when attempting to do so I get the following error when opening the connection with Snowflake:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.KeyPairAuthenticator.GenerateJwtToken()
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.Authenticator.KeyPairAuthenticator.Authenticate()
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.SFSession.Open()
   at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open()
```

I also tried to create a simple Console App (.Net Framework 4.7.2) and this issue **does not** happen.
Therefore it seems to occur only with Azure Functions (.Net Core 3.1).

What could be causing this error? Does Snowflake .Net Driver support .Net Core Framework?

Comment: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net "Library target is under .NET Framework 4.7.2 **and .NET Standard 2.0**" so it should work. Suggest reporting a bug at https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/issues